# Need to remove all existing footers in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

What is the best way to remove all footers from a `ListView`? There does not seem to be a `removeAllFooterViews()` method.  So how does one reliably remove all the footers that have been added? If an android view can have a `removeAllViews()` why can't a `ListView` has a `removeAllFooterViews()`.  Why not a method to retrieve all footers that have been added.  I mean has anyone ever built an add/remove container without an iterate option? This is nonsense.

Any opinions on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through the positions in the list adapter and check if each one is a footer using [`getItemViewType()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemViewType%28int%29). If you get `ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_HEADER_OR_FOOTER`, you can remove it. (If you have both headers and footers, you will need a more sophisticated solution, such as keeping track of all the footers yourself as you add them.)

Comment: Good suggestions.  Not clear on why android does not maintain this itself. After all it has an addFooterView() and removeFooterView() There should really be a removeAllFooterViews().  In the meantime there should be some consensus developed on how to handle multiple footer views.

Comment: Upvote for common sense: "such as keeping track of all the footers yourself as you add them."

Comment: Unfortunately even if you keep track of them (as I already am) there can be a lot of issues in removing them, null pointer exceptions and even class caste exceptions for the adapter.

Comment: @Sam lets face it.  The SDK on add/remove footers is broken.  No where does it advise removing a footer view can cause common yet uncommon anomalies.

Comment: "Remember that which ceases to be helpful, ceases to be relevent" Code Droid 2012

Comment: but one thing, Yet, I didn't added the footer, but  call to remove that footer ( global Footer) as listView.removeFooterView(footerText); -- this return no exception, is it correct situation ?